# Error after deploying website when new user signs up

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I recently deployed my website. On local machine everything works. Online everything seems to be working fine except when I try to sign up a new account I get an error

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   173.194.196.109:587
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond 173.194.196.109:587
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond 173.194.196.109:587]
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) +185
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) +506
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6) +6640228
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +302
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +23
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) +328
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint) +141
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
>   +222    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() +45    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1557
>
> [SmtpException: Failure sending mail.]
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1905
>   Cleaners.Controllers.SController.ConfirmationEmail(String username) in
>   c:\Users\Nechemia\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Babyitter4\Babyitter4\Controllers\SController.cs:916
>   Cleaners.Controllers.SController.Signup(HttpPostedFileBase Images,
>   String username, String firstName, String lastName, String password,
>   String familyRav, DateTime birthday, String neighborhood, String
>   reference, String referenceNumber, String ContactType, String
>   PhoneNumber, String carrier, String transportation, Int32 price,
>   Nullable`1 Sunday1From, Nullable`1 Sunday1Until, Nullable`1
>   Sunday2From, Nullable`1 Sunday2Until, Nullable`1 Monday1From,
>   Nullable`1 Monday1Until, Nullable`1 Monday2From, Nullable`1
>   Monday2Until, Nullable`1 Tuesday1From, Nullable`1 Tuesday1Until,
>   Nullable`1 Tuesday2From, Nullable`1 Tuesday2Until, Nullable`1
>   Wednesday1From, Nullable`1 Wednesday1Until, Nullable`1 Wednesday2From,
>   Nullable`1 Wednesday2Until, Nullable`1 Thursday1From, Nullable`1
>   Thursday1Until, Nullable`1 Thursday2From, Nullable`1 Thursday2Until,
>   Nullable`1 Friday1From, Nullable`1 Friday1Until, Nullable`1
>   Friday2From, Nullable`1 Friday2Until, Nullable`1 Saturday1From,
>   Nullable`1 Saturday1Until, Nullable`1 Saturday2From, Nullable`1
>   Saturday2Until) in c:\Users\Nechemia\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Babyitter4\Babyitter4\Controllers\SController.cs:319
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +2430
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41()
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>   +58    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
>   +24    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +99    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +16    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +16    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +25
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +16    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9765121    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Where is this being hosted?  The exception details indicate that your code is trying to send an email via an SMTP server, but the connection to that SMTP server failed. This may be due to the web host not allowing that outbound connection, or the SMTP server not allowing your inbound connection

Comment: 1and1.com sending through gmail

Comment: You're better off using a proper email service - apparently (possibly old information) GMail will cap you at 99 messages within a 24 hour period.  Email services - such as SendGrid - have free tiers that allow much more.  That said, have you tried using port 465 with TSL/SSL enabled?

Comment: Food for thought: http://docs.mailpoet.com/article/61-sending-with-gmail-doesnt-work

Comment: hmm here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?ctx=gsidentifier it says 500 a day